# Pyomo sensitivity analysis

Tags: pyomo

Is there a reasonnably straightforward way (in very few lines of code) to request a sensitivity analysis of an `AbstractModel` in Pyomo, regardless of the solver and the problem? If so, will the results of this sensitivity analysis be accessible through Pyomo or Python objects?

I suspect it might have something to do with the `opt.solve(model)` code line (where `opt` is a`SolverFactory` instance and `model` is a previously defined `AbstractModel`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyomo does not currently include tools for sensitivity analysis although we are in the preliminary stages of developing a sensitivity analysis extension. This extension is at least a year away from being included in a release. There are a few alternatives to consider which will require some coding effort to achieve your goal. First, you could use the `gjh` "solver" to get derivatives back from your model. See the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/zydoEGLarYU) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyomo-forum/0Z5lXIub4jM/JMtyQGnwCgAJ). You can also use SIPOPT to get some sensitivity information following the example [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/suffixes/sipopt_hicks.py). Finally, symbolic differentiation has been prototyped in Pyomo using Sympy. This feature is currently undocumented and subject to change but you can see examples of how to use it [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/core/tests/unit/test_symbolic.py).

One caveat with all of these is that they will not work on an `AbstractModel`, they must be applied to a `ConcreteModel`. This is because abstract models are not constructed and don't include any expressions from which derivatives can be extracted.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hints, this might prove itself very useful. I am looking forward for this new functionnalitty, Pyomo has been a very good tool from up to now!